# Install ibm_db module on linux raises an error

Tags: python-3.x, pip, db2

When I install the ibm_db module with pip localy (Windows) it works fine. But when I try to install the module with pip in my Gitlab project (Linux) it fails. First it I had to download the db2 driver manually, untar it to a folder and set the "IBM_DB_HOME" variable to the folder. I did it but now I get an other error. Here is the log.

```
$ python --version
Python 3.11.2
$ pip --version
pip 23.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)
$ cp -R db2driver ~/
$ ls -l ~/db2driver/clidriver
total 44
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr  4 08:25 bin
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr  4 08:25 bnd
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr  4 08:25 cfg
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr  4 08:25 cfgcache
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Apr  4 08:25 conv
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr  4 08:25 include
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr  4 08:25 lib
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr  4 08:25 license
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr  4 08:25 msg
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr  4 08:25 properties
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr  4 08:25 security64
$ export IBM_DB_HOME=~/db2driver/clidriver
$ pip install ibm_db==3.1.4
Looking in indexes: https://our.repo/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-repo/simple
Collecting ibm_db==3.1.4
  Downloading https://our.repo/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-repo/packages/packages/a5/fa/0a8e250b54b6479304f6af2784b94fecafe6954fd3d3daedc0a3c2c1b262/ibm_db-3.1.4.tar.gz (1.4 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.4/1.4 MB 42.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Installing backend dependencies: started
  Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Building wheels for collected packages: ibm_db
  Building wheel for ibm_db (pyproject.toml): started
  Building wheel for ibm_db (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for ibm_db (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [625 lines of output]
      <string>:421: UserWarning: Detected usage of IBM Data Server Driver package. Ensure you have downloaded 64-bit package of IBM_Data_Server_Driver and retry the ibm_db module install
      
      Detected 64-bit Python
      Pre-requisite check [gcc] : Passed
      Pre-requisite check [Python.h] : Passed
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
      copying ibm_db_dbi.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
      copying testfunctions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
      copying ibmdb_tests.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/ibm_db_dlls
      copying ibm_db_dlls/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/ibm_db_dlls
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/certs
      copying certs/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/certs
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests/test_159a_FetchAssocSeveralRows_02.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests/test_047_FetchTupleMany_06.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests/test_035_FetchRow_01.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests/test_051_SetAutocommit_01.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests/test_booleanInsertSelect.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests/test_146a_CallSPINAndOUT_Blob_Param.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests/test_recreateDB.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests/test_008_ColumnInfo.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests/test_232_FieldTypePosName.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-
...
...
...
      copying ibm_db_tests/test_142_BindParamSelectStmtMultipleParams_02.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/ibm_db_tests
      running egg_info
      writing ibm_db.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to ibm_db.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to ibm_db.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'ibm_db.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'clidriver'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'config.py'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'ibm_db.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      copying ibm_db_dlls/ibm_db.dll -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/ibm_db_dlls
      copying certs/ibm_certs.pem -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/certs
      copying ibm_db_tests/pic1.jpg -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests/pic1_out.jpg -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests/spook.png -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests/spook_out.png -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/ibm_db_tests
      running build_ext
      building 'ibm_db' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
      gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/root/db2driver/clidriver/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.11 -c ibm_db.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/ibm_db.o
      ibm_db.c: In function ‘_python_ibm_db_free_result_struct’:
      ibm_db.c:385:35: warning: unused variable ‘prev_ptr’ [-Wunused-variable]
        385 |     param_node *curr_ptr = NULL, *prev_ptr = NULL;
            |                                   ^~~~~~~~
      ibm_db.c:385:17: warning: unused variable ‘curr_ptr’ [-Wunused-variable]
        385 |     param_node *curr_ptr = NULL, *prev_ptr = NULL;
            |                 ^~~~~~~~
...
...
...
      ibm_db.c:9217:40: warning: ‘%s’ directive writing up to 1039 bytes into a region of size 1024 [-Wformat-overflow=]
       9217 |         sprintf(error, "Fetch Failure: %s", IBM_DB_G(__python_stmt_err_msg));
            |                                        ^~
      ibm_db.c:9217:9: note: ‘sprintf’ output between 16 and 1055 bytes into a destination of size 1039
       9217 |         sprintf(error, "Fetch Failure: %s", IBM_DB_G(__python_stmt_err_msg));
            |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      ibm_db.c:9434:61: warning: ‘%s’ directive writing up to 1039 bytes into a region of size 1019 [-Wformat-overflow=]
       9434 |                         sprintf(error, "Failed to LOB Data: %s",
            |                                                             ^~
      ibm_db.c:9434:25: note: ‘sprintf’ output between 21 and 1060 bytes into a destination of size 1039
       9434 |                         sprintf(error, "Failed to LOB Data: %s",
            |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       9435 |                             IBM_DB_G(__python_stmt_err_msg));
            |                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      ibm_db.c:9420:71: warning: ‘%s’ directive writing up to 1039 bytes into a region of size 1013 [-Wformat-overflow=]
       9420 |                             sprintf(error, "Failed to fetch LOB Data: %s",
            |                                                                       ^~
      ibm_db.c:9420:29: note: ‘sprintf’ output between 27 and 1066 bytes into a destination of size 1039
       9420 |                             sprintf(error, "Failed to fetch LOB Data: %s",
            |                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       9421 |                                 IBM_DB_G(__python_stmt_err_msg));
            |                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/ibm_db.o -L/root/db2driver/clidriver/lib -L/usr/local/lib -ldb2 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/ibm_db.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
      /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldb2
      collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for ibm_db
ERROR: Could not build wheels for ibm_db, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
Failed to build ibm_db
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

The library I downloaded manually was from the following URL

```
https://github.com/ibmdb/db2drivers/raw/main/clidriver/linuxx64_odbc_cli.tar.gz
```

Now I am not shure was the error is.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Stephan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the error message    `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldb2`
it means the linker is unable to locate your Db2 libraries.

Check the instructions on the [readme](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb) page and in particular export the environment variable  **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** , before building, with an entry to include the directory that has your Db2 libraries :

(for example on linux `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$IBM_DB_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` )

Comment: Hi mao, I tried it but I had to link the library by myself like `ln -s $IBM_DB_HOME/lib/libdb2.so.1 /usr/lib/libdb2.so`. This works for me.